# How to combine rules in gitlab ci/cd

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to create rule for:
`changes in folder foo && branch = master && tag pushed`

My current rules not working:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - changes:
        - foo/**/*
```

Looks like gitlab take like a OR.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 21):

As stated in the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#complex-rule-clauses):

> To conjoin if, changes, and exists clauses with an AND, use them in the same rule.

So it should be:

```yaml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
        changes:
          - foo/**/*
```